# Add a column filter to a detailed view (list view) in c#

Tags: c#, listview

i'm looking for a way to add column filters to detailed view (list view) in c# ?
(i found ways to sort the list ... but need a way to filter items out)

any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind ... found the solution .. 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/listviewfilter.aspx